# What do people do on National Anthem Day in Romania

Tags: public-holidays, romania, local-knowledge

While planning a trip, I was looking through a list of [public holidays for Romania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holidays_in_Romania) on wikipedia.

I'm interested to learn about National Anthem Day ("Deșteaptă-te, române!").

According to the article, it is not an official public holiday, but it is recognized as an annual observance. What does this mean? What do people on National Anthem Day? Is there anything that a visitor to Romania should be aware of with regards to National Anthem Day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "[National Anthem Day in Romania](http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/romania/national-anthem-day)", it would seem that usually people celebrate it in public places.

There are key historical spots that attract crowds, such as the Tomb of the Unknown Soldier in Carol Park in Bucharest.

Celebrations include a public ceremony attended by political and religious leaders, officers serving the armed forces, and war veterans.

In terms of dress, official uniforms are worn, the national flag is raised, and the national anthem is performed on the day.